# Validation of multiple items in an array

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I've got a `FileLocations` class which stores the path's to specific files.

```
class FileLocations
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $files = [];

    /**
     * @param array $files
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function __construct (array $files) {
        if (!$this->areValidFiles($files)) {
            throw new Exception;
        }
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    /**
     * @param $files
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function areValidFiles (array $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            return is_file($file);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFiles () {
        return $this->files;
    }
}
```

I've wanted to validate each file (with `is_file`), so i made the `areValidFiles` function and looped through every array index which it gets. On each array item it's doing an check.

When i run this code like this:

```
$fileLocations  = new FileLocations(['doesExist.js', 'doesnotExist.js']);
var_dump($fileLocations->getFiles());
```

It only does the validation for the first file and doesn't even reconize that there is a second file passed in the arguments.

It also doesn't throw an exception.

**Questions**

- How does this come that it only reconizes one file in the validation
  and not throws an exception on the second file that doesn't even
  exist?
- How can I make it so that i will be able to pass more parameters
  inside the `areValidFiles` function?

Comment: The `return is_file()` is causing the foreach to abort after the first time. Remove that is the first step to solve this. What should happen when it finds a file that does not exist?

Comment: @Bjorn It should throw an Exception in the __construct method. What do you mean with removing it?

Comment: try to return an array with booleans in areValidFiles()

Comment: No, it returns true. The `return is_file()` basically exits the function, stopping it from looping through the rest of the array.

Comment: Why not throw the exception directly? I.e.: `foreach $files as $file: if not is_file($file): throw new Exception`. Otherwise you could replace the `throw new Exception` with `return false`.

Comment: @KA_lin But then i cant inject an if statement anymore right?

Comment: @Bas What if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `areValidFiles` function should be rewritten:

```
private function areValidFiles (array $files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!is_file($file))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as what i did? Except reversing the true with the false?

Comment: No. it's not the same.

Comment: Can i still do this then? : `return !is_file($file)` ?

Comment: Nope. You only want to `return` when it finds a file that does not exist. You do not want to `return` on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Understand that when you use `return` your function stops working **immediately**.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Didn't know. Accepting answer when i can.

Answer (score 1):

I`d do something like:

```
   /**
     * @param $files
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function areValidFiles (array $files) {
        $files = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $files[$file] = is_file($file);
        }
        return $files;
    }
$fileLocations  = new FileLocations(['doesExist.js', 'doesnotExist.js']);
$fileLocations['doesExist.js'] //true
$fileLocations['doesnotExist.js'] //false
```

OR using exceptions:

```
    private function areValidFiles (array $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if(!is_file($file)){
                throw new Exception('Invalid file: '.$file);
            }
        }
    }

try{
    $fileLocations  = new FileLocations(['doesExist.js', 'doesnotExist.js']);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont really like the way of looping through an array of boolean's. I'd stick with u_mulder's way :)

Comment: Okay, but this way you would know which file is invalid :)

Comment: Indeed. But i dont really need that :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a watcher to your function instead of using `return` after `is_file`

```
private function areValidFiles (array $files) {
    $are_all_files_valid = true;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            $are_all_files_valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $are_all_files_valid;
}
```

Comment: This is nice too, but i preffer @u_mulder 's answer :)